# Photo to Base64 in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, base64, windows-phone-8.1, writeablebitmap

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINPRT). User picks photo from gallery and this image has to be uploaded on server. So, i need to convert it into Base64 string.

So, flow I am following for Photo to Base64 string is:
**args.Files[0]** > **StorageFile** >   **IRandomAccessStream**  > **WriteableBitmap** > **pixelstream** > **base64string** 
But the image could be very large, so I am resizing it into 48x48, and converting it into pixels and then string.

The app crashes or phone gets stuck on **Convert.ToBase64String(pixels);**

Am I doing this wrong? Am i still taking the pixels of full dimension image into conversion?

```
   public async void ConvertPictureToBase64()
        {

            string ImageIntoBase64String = "";

            WriteableBitmap WriteableBitmapObject = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            var storageStream = await StorageFileObject.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            IRandomAccessStream IRandomAccessStreamObject = await StorageFileObject.OpenReadAsync();
            WriteableBitmapObject.SetSource(IRandomAccessStreamObject);

            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, storageStream);
            var pixelStream = WriteableBitmapObject.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            var pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
            await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)WriteableBitmapObject.PixelWidth, (uint)WriteableBitmapObject.PixelHeight, 48, 48, pixels);

            ImageIntoBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();    
        }
```

Comment: Please add more details about the crash - what type of exception, exception message etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my method to compress the image and then convert it into a Base64 String.

**Note:** I'm using the WriteableBitmapEx extension class to resize the image. Also, the WriteableBitmap class needs to be instantiated on the UI thread, so if you're running this method on a background Task like I am, you'll have to pass the reference to the page you're in, so that the method will be able to get the current UI dispatcher to work on when it's using the WriteableBitmap class.

Here it is:

```cs
public static async Task<String> ToCompressedBase64(this StorageFile imageFile, Page localPage)
{
    //Get the stream from the StorageFile
    IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Original size ---> " + imageStream.ToFileSize());

    //Compresses the image if it exceedes the maximum file size
    imageStream.Seek(0);
    BitmapDecoder compressDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    PixelDataProvider compressionData = await compressDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
    byte[] compressionBytes = compressionData.DetachPixelData();

    //Set target compression quality
    BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
    BitmapTypedValue qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(0.5, PropertyType.Single);
    propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);

    imageStream.Seek(0);
    imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    BitmapEncoder compressionEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, imageStream, propertySet);
    compressionEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                                    compressDecoder.PixelWidth, compressDecoder.PixelHeight,
                                    compressDecoder.DpiX, compressDecoder.DpiY, compressionBytes);
    await compressionEncoder.FlushAsync();

    //Create a BitmapDecoder from the stream
    BitmapDecoder resizeDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Old height and width ---> " + resizeDecoder.PixelHeight + " * " + resizeDecoder.PixelWidth + "\nCompressed size ---> " + imageStream.ToFileSize());
#endif
    //Resize the image if needed
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    localPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        const int maxImageWidth = 48;
        if (resizeDecoder.PixelWidth > maxImageWidth)
        {
            //Resize the image if it exceedes the maximum width
            int newHeight = (int)(maxImageWidth * resizeDecoder.PixelHeight / resizeDecoder.PixelWidth);
            WriteableBitmap tempBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)resizeDecoder.PixelWidth, (int)resizeDecoder.PixelHeight);
            imageStream.Seek(0);
            await tempBitmap.SetSourceAsync(imageStream);
            WriteableBitmap resizedImage = tempBitmap.Resize(maxImageWidth, newHeight, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

            //Assign to imageStream the resized WriteableBitmap
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream resizedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await resizedImage.ToStream(resizedStream, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);
            imageStream = resizedStream;
        }
        completionSource.SetResult(true);
    }).Forget();
    await completionSource.Task;           

    //Converts the final image into a Base64 String
    imageStream.Seek(0);

    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    PixelDataProvider pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New height and width ---> " + decoder.PixelHeight + " * " + decoder.PixelWidth + "\nSize after resize ---> " + imageStream.ToFileSize());
#endif
    byte[] bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();

    //Encode image
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, encoded);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, decoder.PixelWidth, decoder.PixelHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY, bytes);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    encoded.Seek(0);

    //Read bytes
    byte[] outBytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
    await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length);

    //Create Base64
    return Convert.ToBase64String(outBytes);
}
```

**Note:** I'm using a TaskCompletionSource instead of awaiting the RunAsync call on the page dispatcher because if you call it with an async Action, you can't actually await it, as it returns a Task to the caller and that method returns it without awaiting the Action to be completed.
So I ended up with the inner async Action that was still running after the control went wack to the main method.
Using that TaskCompletionSource and awaiting it solves the problem though :)

The Forget method is just a method I have to suppress the VS warning when you call an async method inside an async method without awaiting it.

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void Forget(this IAsyncAction action) { }
```

You can call it like this:

```cs
Task<String> base64ResizedImage = Task.Run(async () => await args.Files[0].ToCompressedBase64(this));
```

Also, my method resizes the image if its width exceedes a given value (I set 48 as you said in your question).
If you want to check for the height as well, just edit that part and check on both the image bounds :)

Comment: Dear brother, It's not working in Windows Phone 8.1 WINRT (Store App). actually its code for Windows 8.1 Silverlight. i tried to modify it but its giving errors. Can you please tell me the changes for Windows phone 8.1 WinRT

Comment: An illegal state change was requested. Error on dispatcher

Comment: It still gets OutOfMemoryException

Comment: You're wrong, I have this code inside my WP8.1 app and it runs fine, this is **not** for Silverlight.

Comment: If it is giving out of memory exceptions, declare all WriteableBitmap objects in the constructor !